# Preparing an automated testing using javascript for testing a module

Tags: javascript, node.js

The module has three pages which change one by one when clicked on the next or prev button. I am able to click it by writing the click method twice. How do I make it work in one test? Do I have to use a loop or any other way. Please suggest JavaScript, my arrow environment is new to me. We are using nodejs.

Secondly, they are adding an auto rotate feature to this module, for which also I have to prepare automation test. Please suggest how to go about automating testing this feature.

> http://att.yahoo.com/
>   (check Attspotlight module)

For your convenience, here is the current code I wrote for the module:

```
YUI.add("cdt-att-spotlight-func-tests", function(Y) {

  'use strict';

  var Utils = Y.Media.Cdt.FuncTestUtils;

  Y.Media.Cdt.FuncTestUtils.DebugMode=true;

  var selectors = {

          module: "#mediabcarouselmixedlpca_2",
          /*title: ".heading",
                  numberSlot: ".yui-carousel-pagination",
          clickButtons: ".ymg-nav-buttons",*/
          nextButton: ".yui-carousel-next",
          prevButton: ".yui-carousel-prev",
                  visibleImage:".img-wrap",
                  /*linkText_bestdeals: ".txt",
                  linkText_CheckGoPhone:".txt",
                  linkText_greatdeals:".txt",*/
                  linkText: ".txt"

  };

  var suite = new Y.Test.Suite("Cdt Att Spotlight Func Test Suite");

  suite.add(new Y.Test.Case({

    setUp: function() {

         // Find our module...
        this.module = Y.one(selectors.module);

     // Define our components...
        this.components = {
            nextButton: this.module.one(selectors.nextButton),
                prevButton: this.module.one(selectors.prevButton),
                visibleImage: Utils.track.selector(this.module, selectors.visibleImage),
                linkText: this.module.one(selectors.linkText)

        }; 


        this.module.scrollIntoView();

    },

     "Verify MediaCdtAttSpotlight module loaded": function() {

         this.module.should.be.visibleToUser();

       },



        "Verify Image showed in the module": function() {

      var visibleImage = this.components.visibleImage.current();

      this.wait(function() {

        visibleImage.should.be.visibleToUser();

      }, 2000);

    },



       "Verify the Link Text is visible": function() {

        this.components.linkText.should.be.visibleToUser();

      },


    "Verify clicking next button to scroll left": function() {

      this.components.nextButton.simulate("click");

      this.wait(function() {

      }, 3000);

    },


    "Verify clicking next button1 to scroll left": function() {

      this.components.nextButton.simulate("click");

      this.wait(function() {

      }, 3000);

    },


     "Verify clicking prev button to scroll right": function() {

      this.components.prevButton.simulate("click");

      this.wait(function() {

      }, 2000);
    },


     "Verify clicking prev button1 to scroll right": function() {

      this.components.prevButton.simulate("click");

      this.wait(function() {

      }, 2000);
    }



  }));

  Y.Test.Runner.add(suite);

}, "0.1", { requires: ["test", "node", "node-event-simulate", "chai-yui", "cdt-func-test-utils"]});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This question is targeted towards nodejs module testing in general, not Arrow. I don't want to delete it as the author is looking for clarification of some things in the comments of my anwser. I will be happy to delete this anwser if it is requested.

I would reccomend mocha http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/. It is a great testing framework that is very popular. When combined with the module *should*, you can write simple tests, like this.

```
require('should');

describe('Array', function(){
  describe('#indexOf()', function(done){
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function(){
      [1,2,3].indexOf(5).should.equal(-1);
      [1,2,3].indexOf(0).should.equal(-1);
      done();
    })
  })
})
```

You can then set up a free web service called travis ci https://travis-ci.org/ to run your tests whenever you push to github. I am using these services for my modules and am very happy.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the response. But I cant use mocha, I have to run my test cases in arrow environment. Most importantly what I am looking for is from the html code below how will u get the text of 1-2 of 3 text
how to get the text of pagination?

Comment: <div id="mediabcarouselmixedlpca_2" class="yom-mod yom-bcarousel ymg-carousel ymg-carousel_2">
<div class="hd">
<div class="yui-carousel-nav">
<div class="heading">
<div class="controls ymg-carousel-nav-wrap">
<div class="pagination yui-carousel-pagination">1 - 1 of 3</div>
<div class="ymg-nav-buttons">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bd">
</div>

Comment: How will get the above thing done in java script ? sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: Oops, sorry, I missed the arrow part :(.  I don't know much about arrow or yui, so I can't help you much here. My suggestion to use Travis still stands though, as you can run arrow tests on it (in fact, the official arrow libiary does https://travis-ci.org/yahoo/arrow .

Comment: That's Alright. Thanks for the information. 2nd Question up here: Do you know how can I handle an Auto-Rotate feature (Changes the images after few secs automatically). I want to automate test it using javaSrcipt. What must I verify as a Tester?